# VBScript returning 0 rows when ADSIEdit returns correct number of rows

Tags: vbscript, ldap, adodb, adsi

I've been banging my head against this for the last two days or so, and without much success - regardless what I try. 
When I run a query to retrieve share volumes which ends with a specific ending, I get it to work properly in ADSIEdit - but not in my VBScript. Really odd, as I'm using exactly the same query.

The ADSIEdit query is configured like so:

- Name: Test
- Root of Search: DC=ad,DC=server,DC=com
- Query String: (&(objectCategory=volume)(objectClass=volume)(cn=K_*))
- Query Scope: Subtree search.

  - Search results: 11 records where the cn starts with K_
  - VbScript results: 1 record (!?!?)

If I change the query string to (last part) **(uNCName=*\5cOst-gro))** instead, which is what I really want (the first query string I gave was for testing purposes), in ADSIEdit I get 7 rows returned - in my VBScript none!

Here's my (current) VBScript code:

```
Set objDomain = getObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

strDNSDomain = objDomain.Get("defaultNamingContext")

objCommand.CommandText = "Select Name, uNCName, ManagedBy from "_
    & "'LDAP://DC=ad,DC=server,DC=com'" _
        & " where objectClass='volume' and uNCName = '*\5cOst-gro'"
        'The below is not working either!
'objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://DC=ad,DC=server,DC=com>;"_
'    & "(&(objectCategory=volume)(objectClass=volume)(uNCName=*\5cOst-gro));"_
'       & "name,uNCName;subtree"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute( , , adCmdTableDirect)
avarGetRowsArray = objRecordset.GetRows(intNumRows, BkMrk) ' returns 0 too
objRecordSet.MoveFirst ' Doesn't help
If objRecordSet.Supports(adApproxPosition)=True Then
    nrRecords=objRecordSet.RecordCount
End If
if not objRecordSet.EOF Then 
    do While Not objRecordSet.EOF 
        MsgBox "Match found! " & objRecordSet.Fields("name").Value, vbOKOnly, "Match found"
        objRecordSet.MoveNext 
    Loop 
Else 
    MsgBox "No matches found. " & UBound(avarGetRowsArray), vbOKOnly, "No matches!"
end If
```

Hoping someone can help. I've [read countless topics](http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=either%20bof%20or%20eof%20is%20true%20or%20the%20current%20record%20has%20been%20deleted.%20requested%20operation%20requires%20a%20current%20record) on it but failed with each and every one :(

EDIT: I've think I've nailed it down to a trust/permission issue. When I run adfind (or dsquery) on the AD machine, it returns the correct number of rows. However, if I run it on the client machine, it returns the wrong amount of rows. The question now is, **how** do I do to solve it?

SERVER:

```
D:\Tests>adfind -c -f "(&(objectCategory=volume)(objectClass=volume)(uNCName=*\5
cOst-gro))"

AdFind V01.45.00cpp Joe Richards (joe@joeware.net) March 2011

Using server: ad.server.com:389
Directory: Windows Server 2003
Base DN: DC=ad,DC=server,DC=com

7 Objects returned

D:\Tests>
```

CLIENT:

```
C:\tests>adfind -c -f "(&(objectCategory=volume)(objectClass=volume)(uNCName=*\5
cOst-gro))"

AdFind V01.45.00cpp Joe Richards (joe@joeware.net) March 2011

Using server: ad.server.com:389
Directory: Windows Server 2003
Base DN: DC= DC=ad,DC=server,DC=com

0 Objects returned

C:\tests>adfind -c -f "(&(objectCategory=volume)(objectClass=volume)(cn=K_*))"

AdFind V01.45.00cpp Joe Richards (joe@joeware.net) March 2011

Using server: ad.server.com:389
Directory: Windows Server 2003
Base DN: DC= DC=ad,DC=server,DC=com

1 Objects returned
```

Comment: In your query, you want to use (uNCName=*\5cOst-gro).  What does the *\5 indicate to your mind.  i wonder if there is an escaping issue.

Comment: @geoffc the \5c is a replacement for backslash (\\) and I took that from ADSIEdit. in other words, it will search for *\Ost-gro in this case (a successful hit would be ad.server.com\shares\Ost-gro for example)

Comment: #Exodus So I wonder if the escaping accounts for the differences in ADSIEdit vs VBScript.

Comment: @geoffc That was my first suspicion too, but I've tested both, and it makes no difference... I did, however, find out something interesting. I used dsquery and adfind to do some more testing, and the queries return differently depending on WHERE I run them from; the actual AD server or the client. I think I'm onto something...

Answer (score 0):

@exodus: your escaping sign is the error. you have to use "\5C" (upper case) if you want to search for a backslash.
hier is a link for more details: http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help either :(

My current workaround is to use an exported csv file from the A.D and iterate over that, but it's **not optimal** as there'd be manual work to remember, and export, the csv file every time a group has been added or removed.

I'm still fairly certain this has got to do with some permission or similar, I just haven't had time to investigate it thoroughly yet.